# Adding references for SilverLight ToolKit 5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

I have googled so much but couldn't find any solution so i have decided to put my question over here....so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I download the Silverlight toolkit from here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435 [**Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011.msi**].
after I have installed it

1. I found  "**Microsoft Silverlight 5 Toolkit December 2011**" in my windows7 ultimates "**ALL PROGRAMS**" list.
   but when I clicked on "**Toolkit Samples**" it shows me "**Missing Shortcut**" ***window***.
2. and when I unzip the "**Sample source code**" and Open the solution "**Silverlight.Controls.Samples.sln**" it loads two projects in my "**Solution Explorer**"

   **(i) Controls.Samples** and **(ii) Controls.samples.Common**
3. I have found that when I click on "**References**" node many referances are missing.
   for example: (i)  System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit
           (ii) System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.toolkit
               **etc.....**
4. **I couldn't understand where to find the DLL(s) which could help to get rid of the missing references issue.**

**NOTE:** I have checked both folder named "**Binaries**" in "**Sample source code.zip**" and "**source code.zip**" for Required DLLs...but it didn't help me....

Comment: Too much bold, my eyes! Seriously, bolding text should be used for special emphasis only, not every keyword (you could use code formatting for that if you want).

Comment: ohhh.....sorry...i will bear in mind this suggestion

Answer (score 11):

I found them here:

`<ProgramFiles>\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin\`

Comment: thank you so much for answer... which dll i have too add as reference first?

Comment: order doesn't matter really, just add them as required

Comment: StaWho Could you please tel me where is the The  'ObjectCollection' class resides.........because i am getting the following error......The type or namespace name 'ObjectCollection' could not be found......please.....

Comment: Have you looked in the documentation?

Comment: Thank you so much for answer i have solved 'ObjectCollection' could not found issue..........now i have following references are missing....
System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BubbleCreme
System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BureauBlack
System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BureauBlue
System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ExpressionDark.....etc...which are in the second project of the two project in my solution explorer  (ii) Controls.samples.Common.......and referanced in first project(i) Controls.Samples......thank....referance missing error comes in firs project.......thank you..